# Custom title, Bones theme

Tags: customization, title

I'm a total wordpress noob and ran into my first problem. I downloaded [this](http://themble.com/) theme.

My question is how do I change how the `p#logo.h1` is shown. I would like to put a `<br />` in the middle of my title, and half in a custom .

So the html of the title should be something like:

```
<p id="logo><h1>This is a<br /><span id="customtitle">Big title</span></h1></p>
```

How can I change that?

Comment: I don't even know where to start. Hence "I'm a total wordpress noob".

Comment: Go to your header.php in y our theme directory, copy the contents and paste it for us at www.pastebin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your header.php file, replace this line:

```
<p id="logo" class="h1"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></p>
```

with your custom line:

```
<p id="logo><h1>This is a<br /><span id="customtitle">Big title</span></h1></p>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Come back if you need any more help :)